# Rails 3 create new child for a specific parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, for-loop, parent

Hey all! Just joined up on stack overflow, as it has been a helpful resource while starting to learn about Ruby on Rails 3.

I can't seem to find one particular answer though, and maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree for all I know, but hopefully you folks can sort me out here. First some info on what I'm working with:
 - In my web app I have 2 models: Projects and Tasks in a one-to-many relationship.
 - Projects has many Tasks, and Tasks belong to Project 
 - Tasks **IS NOT** a nested resource, as users need to be able to see all current tasks, regardless of which project they are for.
- routes.rb therefore looks like this right now:
 
**resources :projects 

resources :tasks**

In the project show view I display a list of tasks associated with that project. below that there is a link_to for creating a new task that looks like <%= link_to 'New Task', new_task_path, :class => "new-btn" %>. The link_to takes user to the new view for creating a new task. The rendered _form view starts with: <%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>.

Now, I think **I need to pass the project id from the project show view, to the new task view**: but, this is where I am getting lost and possibly, a bit mixed up.

Could someone please point me in the right direction: maybe to a resource outlining all steps involved in doing this, or maybe even provide an outline of the steps involved in the process here.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If current_user returns User object then you should be able to call

```
current_user.projects
```

to get all user's projects.

Defining a relation between user and task may be working (though I am not sure this one).

```
#models/user.rb
has_many :projects
has_many :tasks, :through => :projects
```

In this case simply

```
current_user.tasks
```

should return user's tasks

Comment: Great! All I had to do was define the new HMT relationship and current_user.tasks works fine, just like you said. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You may create nested routes and still be able to show all tasks regardless of the project. Just make sure you have task resource defined later, like

```
resources :projects do |p|
  resources :tasks
end
resources :tasks
```

Now in projects index or show view you can create link like

```
link_to 'New Task', new_project_task_path(project)
```

The task index view may be a little bit tricky. All depends on how you sort these tasks. If, for example, you show them sorted by project then you can create a link like

```
link_to 'New Task', new_project_task_path(task.project)
```

As for forms. In new action you have to get the id from params and put it into task object

```
if (params[:project_id])
  @task.project_id = params[:project_id]
```

In form view you may create hidden field that will save this value

```
f.hidden :project_id
```

This will make it work, but you will not be able to go to the new task without providing project. Better solution it would be to create a select field with all projects. To accomplish that you should do the following:

in models/project.rb

```
def getProjectsList
  projects = Project.all
  projects.map do |p|
    [project.name, project_id]
  end
end
```

in controllers/application_controller.rb

```
def find_projects
  @projects = Project.new.getProjectsList
end
```

in controllers/tasks_controller.rb at the begining

```
before_filter :find_projects, :only => [:new, :edit, :update, :create]
```

in views/tasks/_form

```
f.select :project_id, @projects
```

This way you can always select project and in case there is one given in params it will be already selected

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. An easy one may be to add a parameter to you link and use it in the controller:

In your view:

```
<%= link_to 'New Task', new_task_path(:project_id => @project.id), :class => "new-btn" %>
```

In your tasks controller:

```
def new
  @task = Task.new(:project_id => params[:project_id])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to pass the project ID from the project page to the New Task page is to add it to the query string on your url.  Example HTML would look like this:

```
<a href="/tasks/new?project_id=123" class="new-btn">New Task</a>
```

To get Rails to generate that HTML, you can do this in your ERB:

```
<%= link_to 'New Task', new_task_path(:project_id=>@project.id), :class => "new-btn" %>
```

Next, you need to pass the project ID from New Task page to the action that actually creates the Task.  One way to do that would be to make a hidden input inside your form that contains the project ID so that it will be passed along with the other parameters when the form is submitted.  The HTML would look like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="project_id" value="<%= params[:project_id] %>" />
```

To do this the Rails way, you can set the project ID in the new task action in the TasksController:

```
@task.project_id = params[:project_id]
```

and then do something like this in your view inside the form_for block (I'm not 100% sure on the syntax):

```
<%= f.hidden_field(:project_id) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow! Thanks for all the great info guys! I definitely learned a few neat tricks going through this.

Here is what I have working now:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :projects do |p|  
    resources :tasks  
end  
resources :tasks
```

I'm really happy to learn that that part is possible. Now I can enjoy the benefits of nested resource, but use the original non-nested routes for tasks, as well.

**the link_to in show project view**

```
<%= link_to 'New Task', new_project_task_path(@project), :class => "new-btn" %>
```

**tasks_controller.rb new action**

```
if (params[:project_id])
      @task.project_id = params[:project_id]
    end
```

**new task form hidden field**

```
<%= f.hidden_field :project_id %>
```

That all works great for adding new tasks to projects: but, showing a list of all tasks, related to all projects, that are related to the current user was a little bit trickier, and I wonder if there might be a better way than what I came up with:

**tasks_controller.rb in the index action**

```
@projects = Project.find_all_by_user_id(current_user)
@tasks = Array.new
@projects.each do |p|
    p.tasks.each do |t|
        @tasks << t
    end
end
```

I'm using the "devise" and "cancan" gems for user management(both have been great!). The "current_user" above is simply what you would expect: the currently logged in user. Is this a reasonable solution, or is there a better way of getting all tasks for a user?

Just in case:

```
User has_many Projects, and Project has_many Tasks
```